# No padding for Inline code block

Tags: bug, design, inline-code

Is it just me or inline code CSS does not feel tall enough anymore:

Before text `sample inline` after text.

Before text `With capitals` after text.

Screenshot:

[image]

This is making me claustrophobic.

Chromium 65 and Firefox 59, Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: No repro on windows.